# hour format in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my javascript iam using GetHour and GetMinutes function.For eg:Current Time is 2:03.If in this case i use GetHour(),it returns 2.Instead i need 02.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 6):

```
var hour = GetHour() < 10 ? '0' + GetHour() : GetHour();
```

Comment: You could abstract out the repeated part in your true and false expressions: var hour = (GetHour() < 10 ? '0' : '') + GetHour()

Comment: There is no reason to call the function twice.

Comment: Well the code I was commenting on already called it three times! Unless the GetHour() calls prove to be a performance issue there is nothing wrong with calling a method multiple times in order to express code more concisely.

Comment: replace getHour() with getHours()

Comment: Simon actually the code above calls the function two times as the condition is either true or false.

Comment: h = (h = d.getHours()) < 10 ? '0' + h : h

Comment: Use the above if you want a one-liner solution that calls getHours only once. The only side note is that h has global scope unless you do var h first. In any case, you need var d = new Date()

Answer (score 3):

```
var d,h
d = new Date()
h = (h = d.getHours()) < 10 ? '0' + h : h
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to use an IF statement...

```
var dat = new Date();
var hr = dat.getHour();

if(hr < 10) {
  hr = "0" + hr;
}
```

Comment: replace dat.getHour(); with dat.getHours();

Answer (score 1):

You could always just do

```
var time = new Date();

('0' + time.getDate()).slice(-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function for that. 
Use the following to add a leading 0:

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = new String(date.getHours());

if (hours.length == 1)
{
  hours = "0" + hours;
}
```

Comment: This will never add a trailing zero. "length" is not a valid property on the value returned from `getHours()`, so the code in the if statement will never run.

Comment: +1 you are correct, I needed to make it a string first, before asking the 'length'.

Answer (score 0):

There's a javascript library [here](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/) which looks like it will handle all sorts of date conversions nicely, including formatting dates so that the month is always two digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org) framework there's a [`toPaddedString`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/number#method-topaddedstring) method that does this.

```
a = 2;
a.toPaddedString(2)
// results in "02"
```